# Limit of $f(x-1)$ as $x$ approaches $2$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I go about limits questions like these?

The limit of $f(x-1)$ as $x$ approaches $-2$ is
The limit of $(g(x)+4)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is

Do I just take "$x$" and minus $1$ and plug into $f(x)$ and find the limit?

As in $$\lim_{x\to -2} f(x-1)$$ is $f(2)$ if $x=3$

And for the second one do I just add $4$ to the limit of $g(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is just "a function" we can take any $f$ and examine it to see what is clearly valid or invalid for the limit you provide. Consider the piecewise defined function $f(x) = \frac {1}{x + 3}$ when $x = -3$ and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise. Do you see the problem? I changed $f$ so that it isn't defined at $x = -3$. Now the limit obviously cannot be $f(-3)$. If it were that would mean the limit does not exist. We know it clearly exists because just by graphing the function and looking at it we can see the limit at any point is just $1$.

So really the answer here is that you cannot simplify the limit at all. You can change the point you are approaching though. $\lim_{x \to -2} f(x-1) = \lim_{x \to -3} f(x)$. However, this isn't what I'd call a "useful" substitution. You'd be algebraically rearranging terms but nothing meaningful was accomplished overall. It doesn't help you find the value of the limit in any manner.

You also mention a function $g$ and give a similar limit. Everything above applies. You can just define a $g$ such that the function doesn't exist at the point $x$ is approaching. At that point, you can't determine anything else.

However, by the definition of continuity at a single point $n$, the functions will be continuous at $n$ if and only if the limit as $x$ approaches $n$ is the value of the function at $n$. So in general, you were essentially asking if every function is continuous at $3$ in the case of $f$ and whether every function is continuous at $0$ in the case of $g$. This is obviously not true as $0$ and $3$ do not have any special significance regarding continuity and therefore such a claim would imply that all functions are continuous everywhere. If such a thing were true, continuity would have no meaning as everything would be continuous. The limit would also no meaning and would have no purpose for existing. It would just be a fancy way of saying "evaluate at $x$" as that would be what all limits would simplify to. Since these things are not the case we can also more casually declare with strong confidence that not all limits approaching a point have to equal the function evaluated at that point.